# asp onclientclick fails to call javascript function

Tags: asp.net

ok so every time i try and us onclient click this seem pretty basic but it never works and i have no idea why could some one help me

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function required() {
      alert('Please select at least on documnet to email');
      return false;
  }
```

and here is the asp button

```
<asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Email Forms" id="EmailButton" onClientClick="return required();" onclick="email_Click" />
```

Comment: do you have the closing </script> tag

Comment: will need to see the entire form, usually its something malformed, are there in errors that can help you in the inspector?

Comment: yes it has closing tag

Comment: ok i will see about posting the whole page thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `return` from onClientClick attribute or try add something like that `onClientClick="function(){return required();}"`

Answer (score 0):

so i figured a work around

1. no jquery support - i guess you cant call functions in a jquery
2. i add UseSubmitBehavior="false" to the buton to i can call the postback manually
3. and my javascript

   function test() {
       var amount = "$45.00";
       var r = confirm("You are about to submit for the amount of " + amount + "!");
       if (r == true) {
           x = "You pressed OK!";
           __doPostBack('paynow', '');
           return true;
       }else {//do nothin}

i had to do the postback in my function in order for it to work right

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts!  Exactly the same issue but I was adding my control to the page script from code behind.
Simple fix:  Use OnClick NOT OnClientClick.

cmd.Attributes.Add("**onClick**", "return cmdClickMe(" & sID & ");")

pnlTest.Controls.Add(cmd)